# Close current tab in Selenium (Selenium, Python)

Tags: python-3.x, macos, selenium, sendkeys

I have a loop that looks like this:

```
for x in range(2000):

    time.sleep(1.5)

    for x in range(3):
        company_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="company_ratings"]/div[' + element_num[0] + ']' + '/div[1]/a')
        element_num.pop(0)
        '''Scrolls to element'''
        desired_y = (company_elem.size['height'] / 2) + company_elem.location['y']
        current_y = (driver.execute_script('return window.innerHeight') / 2) + driver.execute_script('return window.pageYOffset')
        scroll_y_by = desired_y - current_y
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, arguments[0]);", scroll_y_by)
        '''_'''
        time.sleep(0.5)
        company_elem.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + Keys.SHIFT + Keys.RETURN) ##<--- Part I am stuck on.

        time.sleep(2)
        actions.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 'w') ##<--- Part I am stuck on.
        actions.perform()
        time.sleep(1)

    button_next_pg = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="victor-pagination"]/a[' + next_page[0] + ']')
    next_page.pop(0)
    desired_y = (button_next_pg.size['height'] / 2) + button_next_pg.location['y']
    current_y = (driver.execute_script('return window.innerHeight') / 2) + driver.execute_script('return window.pageYOffset')
    scroll_y_by = desired_y - current_y
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, arguments[0]);", scroll_y_by)
    time.sleep(1)
    button_next_pg.click()
```

I click on the element I want and open it up in a new tab using this part:

```
company_elem.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + Keys.SHIFT + Keys.RETURN)
```

However I cant seem to close the tab using this command:

```
actions.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 'w')
actions.perform()
```

I've tried closing the tab in a few different ways but nothing seems to work, it seems to me that selenium is stuck on the first page.

Do I need to somehow switch to the new tab and then close it? Or I am just doing something completely wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What is `COMMAND ` in keys ?

Comment: @cruisepandey I am on a mac so you use command instead of ctrl as a shortcut for closing a chrome tab

Comment: you do need to switch the driver to the new tab.  There's a switchTo method for that.  (Use .executeScript("close();"); to close current tab... and remember that you'll need to switch the driver back... after that window/tab is closed the driver will be in no man's land.)